# Regex expression for comma and dash seperated text of items

Tags: java, regex

I do have a Java Web Application, where I get some inputs from the user. Once I got this input I have to parse it and the `parsing` part depends on what kind of input I'll get. I decided to use the `Pattern` class of `java` for some of predefined user inputs.

So I need the last 2 regex patterns:

a)Enumaration:

input can be - A03,B24.1,A25.7

The simple way would be to check if there are a comma in there (`[^,]+`) but it will end up with a lot of updates in to parsing function, which I would like to avoid. So, in addition to comma it should check if it starts with

- letter
- minimum 3 letters (combined with numbers)
- can have one dot in the word
- minimum 1 comma (updated it)

b) Mixed

input can be A03,B24.1-B35.5,A25.7

So all of what Enumuration part got, but with addition that it can have a dash minimum one.

I've tried to use multiple online regex generators but didnt get it correct. Would be much appreciated if you can help.

Here is what I got if its B24.1-B35.5 if its just a simple range.

```
"='.{1}\\d{0,2}-.{1}\\d{0,2}'|='.{1}\\d{1,2}.\\d{1,2}-.{1}\\d{1,2}.\\d{1,2}'";
```

Edit1: Valid and Invalid inputs

for a)Enumaration

- A03,B24.1,A25.7 Valid
- A03,B24.1 Valid
- A03,B24.1-B25.1 -Invalid because in this case (enumaration) it should not contain dash
- A03 invalid because no comma
- A03,B24.1 - Valid
- A03 Invalid

for b)Mixed

everything that a enumeration has with addition that it can have dash too.

Comment: @anubhava, its invalid if its a) enumaration case. If its b) mixed case its valid then

Comment: @anubhava, exactly

Comment: split the input on commas, and then verify each individual entry, otherwise your regex becomes complex == error prone

Comment: @diginoise, i've had this idea on my mind right after I asked this question. Because I have regex patterns for simple inputs, and more complex inputs are based on those simple inputs.. So, during the test I'll see if it worth.

Comment: It looks like your entries are very specific for the domain and I sense there could be more rules. For example:
1) is `AAA` a valid entry? 
2) why an enumeration of 1 cannot be comma free?
3) how many digits are allowed within given entry (i.e. is `A123456` valid)?
4) how many digits after the dot are allowed (i.e. is `A0.12345678` valid)?
5) can it have zeros (i.e. `A0.0000`)?

Comment: @diginoise, thanks a lot for showing your interest in to my problem. I appreciate it. To make the answer simple I have to parse the ICD-10 Codes http://www.icd10data.com/ICD10CM/Codes. User can write miltiple ICD-10 Codes and I have to create sql query based on that...

Comment: That's much more precise... I insist that chopping it into segments and verifying each segment makes for much more maintainable code.
It looks like it is always [A-Z] followed by 2 digits and then optional subcodes of 1 to 3 characters (mostly! digits)

Comment: @diginoise, verification of the ICD-10Code is not my main goal. My main goal is to create SQL query to search in the database. So, when I know the input is a34,a54,a64 I generate `like` based sql query. If I know it has dash a34-b54, I create a `range >= <=` sql query..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144825/discussion-between-diginoise-and-daler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for (a) Enumeration part as per your rules:

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{2,}(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,})?(?:,[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{2,}(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,})?)+
```

Rules:

- Verifies that each segment starts with a letter
- Minimum of three letters or numbers `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{2,}`
- Optionally followed by decimal `.` and one or more alphabets and numbers i.e `(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,})?`
- Same thing repeated, and seperated by a comma `,`. Also must have atleast one comma so using `+` i.e `(?:,[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{2,}(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,})?)+`
- `?:` to indicate non-capturing group
- Using `[A-Za-z0-9]` instead of `\w` to avoid underscores

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5GZg79/2/)

For (b) Mixed, you haven't shared too many valid and invalid cases, but based on my current understanding here's what I have:

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{2,}(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,})?(?:[,-][A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{2,}(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,})?)+
```

Note that `,` from previous regex has been replaced with `[,-`] to allow `-` as well!

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wqj7CG/2/)

```
// Will match
A03,B24.1-B35.5,A25.7
A03,B24.1,A25.7
A03,B24.1-B25.1
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** Making sure each group starts with a letter (and not a number)
Thanks to @diginoise and @anubhava for pointing out! Changed `[A-Za-z0-9]{3,}` to `[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{2,}`

Comment: thanks a lot, I always have difficulties with regex your help is much appreciated

Comment: this does not verify "starts with letter"

Comment: Is `123,456` a valid match? This regex matches it.

Comment: well yes, it does not verify if it starts with letter.. 123,456 is wrong

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, I would chop the input by commas and verify each segment separately. Your domain **ICD 10 CM** codes is very well defined and also I would be very wary of any input which could be non valid, yet pass the validation.

Here is my solution:

### regex

`([A-TV-Z][0-9][A-Z0-9](\.?[A-Z0-9]{0,4})?)`

... however I would avoid that.
Since your domain is (moste likely) medical software, people's lives (or at least well being) is at stake. Not to mention astronomical damages and the lawyers ever-chasing ambulances. Therefore avoid the easy solution, and implement the bomb proof one.

You could use the regex to establish that given code is **definitely not valid**. However if a code passes your regex **it does not mean that it is valid**.

### bomb proof method

See this example: `O09.7, O09.70, O09.71, O09.72, O09.73` are **valid entries**, but `O09.1` is **not valid**.

Therefore just get all possible codes. According to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jakebathman/063c50cb9772e4bfc864a9e1ff4ccc8d) there are 42784 different codes. Just load them to memory and any code which is not in the set, is not valid. You could compress said list and be clever about the encoding in memory, to occupy less space, but verbatim all codes are under **300kB** on disk, so **few MBs max** in memory, therefore not a massive cost to pay for a price of people not having left instead of right kidney removed.